# Is Isaiah 2:9-22 about the Second Coming of Christ?

Tags: exegesis, christology, second-coming

We read:

> “People bow down, And each man humbles himself; Therefore do not
> forgive them.
>
> Enter into the rock, and hide in the dust, From the terror of the Lord
> And the glory of His majesty.
>
> The lofty looks of man shall be humbled, The haughtiness of men shall
> be bowed down,
>
> And the Lord alone shall be exalted in that day. For the day of the
> Lord of hosts Shall come upon everything proud and lofty, Upon
> everything lifted up—
>
> And it shall be brought low— Upon all the cedars of Lebanon that are
> high and lifted up, And upon all the oaks of Bashan; Upon all the high
> mountains,
>
> And upon all the hills that are lifted up; Upon every high tower, And
> upon every fortified wall; Upon all the ships of Tarshish, And upon
> all the beautiful sloops.
>
> The loftiness of man shall be bowed down, And the haughtiness of men
> shall be brought low; The Lord alone will be exalted in that day, But
> the idols He shall utterly abolish.
>
> They shall go into the holes of the rocks, And into the caves of the
> earth, From the terror of the Lord And the glory of His majesty, When
> He arises to shake the earth mightily.
>
> In that day a man will cast away his idols of silver And his idols of
> gold, Which they made, each for himself to worship, To the moles and
> bats, To go into the clefts of the rocks,
>
> And into the crags of the rugged rocks, From the terror of the Lord
> And the glory of His majesty, When He arises to shake the earth
> mightily. Sever yourselves from such a man, Whose breath is in his
> nostrils; For of what account is he?” ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭2:9-22

‬ I believe this is an obvious prophecy of the return of Christ from the OT.

Would anyone agree that this is the interpretation?

Or do we have constructive evidence against it? The Book of Revelation seems to have parallels, so I’m convinced.

Comment: @Nigel Cause I’ve been saved about 10 years now and I’ve never heard anyone preach or teach this passage as it pertains to Christ returning.  It would be nice for those who are more complete in OT references (which here, they are simple) to double confirm to my heart that it’s the Second Coming.  If you don’t like the question, that’s fine. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Is Isaiah 2:9-22 about the Second Coming of Christ?**

Possibly, but it will depend on how one interprets this particular passage of Scripture.

Jim Haeffele is a church pastor in the Church of God and he links this passage of the Prophet Isaiah to the Second Coming of Christ.

> [**The Day of the Lord**](https://lifehopeandtruth.com/prophecy/prophets/prophets-of-the-bible/isaiah-the-prophet/)
>
> Prophecies about the coming [Day of the Lord](https://lifehopeandtruth.com/prophecy/revelation/day-of-the-lord/) can be found in the writings of many of the Old Testament prophets, and **Isaiah is no exception. This subject is covered from chapters 2 to 66**. Unlike the dualism of the prophecies to Israel and Judah, most prophecies about the Day of the Lord are for an event yet to come. These foretell a time of awesome and frightening events leading to the return of Christ. Many people think of it as “the end of the world,” although it is really just the end of this present evil age.
>
> Isaiah explains that the Day of the Lord will last for one year (Isaiah 34:8; Isaiah 61:2; Isaiah 63:4). The principle of a day for a year in prophecy also applies to the Day of the Lord (Numbers 14:34; Ezekiel 4:6). It is the year of the “Lord’s vengeance” or God’s wrath (Revelation 6:17).
>
> **In the earlier chapters on this subject (2, 13 and 24), Isaiah describes the effects of God’s wrath on this world. Men will hide in caves in terror (Isaiah 2:19-21)**, the earth will be shaken and possibly moved from its orbit (Isaiah 13:13), and the earth will become almost empty and a total waste (Isaiah 24:1, 3, 6). Isaiah also speaks of the Day of the Lord as a time of war (Isaiah 31:8-9). These events are also described in the seven trumpets of Revelation 8-9.
>
> God further reveals through Isaiah that the “daughter of Babylon” will be destroyed in the Day of the Lord (Isaiah 47:1, 5, 7, 9). These verses are almost identical to those of Revelation 18:7-8, 17-19, 21. This Babylon is the final end-time government and its religious system that will be destroyed at Christ’s return.